# Error in working with jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I'm getting an error at runtime saying that: `could not load com.mysql.jdbc.driver`

But when I'm setting the classpath then at run time I'm getting an error as could not load main class even though I had set up path in advance setting.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently and had to add the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar` to my library. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11 If you're using maven you can just add it in or else download the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with a capital D. Also `Class.forName` no longer is needed; the `jdbc:mysql:` URL suffices.